# How to maintain transaction handling executing two stored procedure from C# code

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I one method in my class Which executing two stored procedure and insert data into three tables. How to handle transaction in that case?

For Example:

```
public class InsertClass
{
   public void AddData()
   {
       try
       {
           Execute Sp1;
           Execute Sp2;
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           throw ex;
       }
   }
}
```

Both SP are for insert.

Comment: can you provide more info? preferably pseudocode to go with your question? for eg: if one stored procedure is inserting data into all the three tables then you can handle it within the stored procedure itself.

Comment: @shamanthGowdraShankaramurthy I have added example code.

Comment: assuming you are using ADO.NET have you tried using [TransactionScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @shamanthGowdraShankaramurthy thank you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
SqlCommand cmd1,cmd2;
con.Open();
cmd1 = new SqlCommand("sp1",con);
cmd2 = new SqlCommand("sp2",con);
SqlTransaction trans = con.BeginTransaction();
cmd1.Transaction = trans;
cmd2.Transaction = trans;
try
{
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    trans.Commit();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    trans.Rollback();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
connection.Open();
SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

try
       {
           Execute Sp1;
           Execute Sp2;
       }
       catch (Exception)
       {
           transaction.Rollback();
           connection.Close();
       }

       transaction.Commit();
```